Azure DevOps acceptance criteria not being shown
Hi I need to edit the acceptance criteria in my ADO and the issue im having is that im not able to see the Acceptance criteria checklist in the project settings inside Acceptance Criterias - Templates. I can add any acceptance criteria to the tasks but I dont see them in the project settings, do I need any special rights to be able to edit them from the project settings?
I have share screen with another DevOps and he can see the acceptance criteria in the project settings

From your description, you are using the feature of Acceptance Criterias extension in Azure DevOps.
Based on my test, I can reproduce the same issue as yours.
I can add any acceptance criteria in Work item -> Acceptance Criterias tab.
For example:

But when I navigate to Project settings ->  Acceptance Criterias ->  Templates, it will show blank page.
For example:

If the Project doesn't contains any acceptance criterias, we can see the details info in acceptance criteria.
For example:

The issue is not related to the permissions in Azure DevOps. It should come from the extension itself.
I suggest that you can report the issue in the  Acceptance Criterias Extension feedback site: Issues
For a workaround, we can modify the Acceptance Criterias in Work item -> Acceptance Criterias tab -> Target Acceptance Criteria -> Edit

